# Django request logs: Can't get them to appear in Cloudwatch

Tags: django, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm struggling to get simple GET requests to show up in Cloudwatch. It seems that all that's appearing are some WARNING and INFO log items, not GET requests. The GET requests ARE appearing in my console when I run things locally.

Here are my logging settings:

```
cloudwatch_level = 'INFO'
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            # exact format is not important, this is the minimum information
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        },
        "aws": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s [%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'aws',
        },
        "watchtower": {
            "level": cloudwatch_level,
            "class": "watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler",
            # From step 2
            'boto3_client': boto3_logs_client,
            "log_group": log_group,
            # Different stream for each environment
            "stream_name": f"logs",
            "formatter": "aws",
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # root logger
        '': {
            'level': cloudwatch_level,
            'handlers': ['console', 'watchtower'],
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'watchtower'],
            'level': cloudwatch_level,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.server': {
            'handlers': ['watchtower'],
            'level': cloudwatch_level,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        "watchtower": {
            "level": cloudwatch_level, 
            "handlers": ["watchtower"], 
            "propagate": True,
        }
    }
})
```

I'm a little confused on the logger setup for Django - should GET requests be logged by the django logger or the django.server logger? I know django.request is only for 400/500 errors, which I have also tried. Nothing seems to put the request logs in Cloudwatch, only my console.